# Azure hosted application Cloudflare throws 524 an error on my server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, cloudflare

I have an application where I am downloading the data to excel based on some selections made by user. The procedure which used to return the data returns the data in 3 minutes as I am using **PIVOT** to display the rows to individual columns for some of the tables. This is OK when I run pointing in to my local SQLserver it works fine. But after hosting it to azure and pointing to the database hosted in server I am seeing the exception after some amount of time **(I guess 1 minute)** in the network tab I see this error stating a time out occurred. I have gone through this post over here [Cloudflare throws 524 an error on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43489801/cloudflare-throws-524-an-error-on-my-server) but my application was hosted in azure not sure if it has any relation with cloud fare. I an unable to figure out how to fix it. Can some one help me.

Here is the sql sample fiddle where I am pivoting data https://dbfiddle.uk/hoJzRWCR. I had around 4-5 tables data where I need to pivot which I am doing in a single query